# Detailed sources of the Sefer Hatanya

Tags: sources-mekorot, tanya

In the standard edition of the Tanya, the Mare Mekomot are not given accurately, e.g Avot Person 2, Nidda Peek 5. Is there a way to reach accurate Mare Mekomot?

Comment: Are you looking at the Hebrew or the English translation? Please provide a few examples of your claim.

Comment: It's the same, I want exactly to know where one topic is in zohar or ets chsyim or other references that are given loosely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a set of sefarim that give very detailed notes, etc, including sources. You can see the first volume [here on hebrewbooks](https://hebrewbooks.org/19787) (all the volumes are there). It is called:

"לקוטי אמרים תניא (בצירוף מ"מ, ליקוטי פירושים ושינוי נוסחאות)"

Also, [the Lessons in Tanya](https://www.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/6237/jewish/Lessons-in-Tanya.htm) probably have the footnotes you're looking for as well:

Comment: The 5 volume set is great, but Kouty still isn’t giving examples of what he means when he says the citations in a standard Tanya aren’t accurate. I think what he means is that some aren’t as specific as he would like. I’ve looked up many of those notes in a standard Tanya and never found them to be “inaccurate”.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I forget all the details, but there were two versions of the Etz Chaim in print at that time, and the early Chabad sefarim used the less popular (but older) one, which leads to footnotes pointing to different sections of the Etz Chaim than is in use today.

Comment: My guess is that Hebrewbooks.org has both versions of Etz Chaim available on the web or to purchase through Lulu.com or Shaftek. But the OP is making it sound like the citations in the Tanya are wrong. I’ve never found them to be actually wrong. Sometimes hard to find, but still accurate.

Comment: @Yaacov I never said the citations are wrong, maybe my English is wrong I mean that the precision is not great for who wants to read in the sources